# JavaScript make Object Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a MySQL query which gets executed by AngularJs Ajax.

It returns data by an array of objects. With console.log() it looks like this:
[image: Result displayed in Google Chrome]

The table from which I get the data looks like this:

```
id     meaning_id     word

1         1           a

2         1           b

3         2           c

4         2           d

5         2           e

6         3           f
```

So as you see, some words have the same meaning_id like others, and I want to collect these words into an object.

I have thought of an Array which contains all the words with the same meaning_id in one index.
For example synonyms[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYd7f.png) should contain the words/objects a and b.

I've tried this:

```
$scope.prepareSynonymsArray = function()
    {
        for(var key in $scope.responseData)
        {
            var obj = $scope.responseData[key];

            if(typeof $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning] == "undefined")
            {
                $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning] = obj;
            }
            else{
                $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning].push(obj);
            }
        }

        console.log($scope.synonyms);
    }
```

But there seems to be a mistake with the push function.
Is there any better way to achieve this? Please give me some suggestions.

Kind regards,
Force0234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is that `$scope.synonyms[obj.meaning]` should be an array (given that you later try to `.push` elements onto it), then in the `undefined` case you must set it to `[ obj ]`, not just `obj`:

```
if (typeof $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning] == "undefined") {
    $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning] = [ obj ];   // initial array with one element
} else {
    $scope.synonyms[obj.meaning].push(obj);   // additional elements
}
```